# Django Rest Framework - One serailizer for API and drf-spectacular

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I have a serializer for DRF, and drf-spectacular.
My serializer works that i expect but in GUI don't present currectly.
So i need to have tho diffrents serializer one for schema and second for endpoint. But i wanna use one, how to fix this ?

My serializer:

```
class GetConversionCasesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    conversionId = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cases = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_cases(self, obj):
        serializer = ResultDataSerializer(ResultData.objects.filter(conversion=obj), many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        return data

    def get_conversionId(self, obj):
        return obj.id
```

Schema serializer:

```
class GetConversionCasesSerializerSchema(serializers.Serializer):
    conversionId = serializers.IntegerField()
    cases = serializers.ListSerializer(child=ResultDataSerializer())
```

Api endpoint:

```
    @extend_schema(request=None, responses=GetConversionCasesSerializerSchema())
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.version == "v1":
        conversion_id = self.kwargs.get('conversion_id')
        instance = Conversion.objects.get(id=conversion_id)
        serializer = GetConversionCasesSerializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When i use to show schema normal selialiser i have:

[image]

in schema serializer:

[image]

How to fix first serializer and have one for schema and get method ?

Comment: Is there a database relationship between `Conversion` and `ResultData` objects?

Comment: @EDG956 yes, Conversion ID is in ResultData table.

Answer (score 0):

Since your models are related, you could just [nest serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). Here's a simple example:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from app.models import Conversion, ResultData


class ResultDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: Define only the attributes you're interested
    class Meta:
        model = ResultData
        fields = '__all__' 


class GetConversionCasesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conversionId = serializers.CharField(source='id')
    cases = ResultDataSerializer(many=True, source='resultdata_set')  # `source` depends on your case

    class Meta:
        model = Conversion
        fields = ('id', 'resultdata_set',)  # add other fields of interest
```

Note that I used `ModelSerializer` everywhere as it already implements some logic for creating resources (not interesting in your use case if it's only returning data to the caller) and automatically maps model fields to DRF fields.